# A new form of modulation?

Tags: wave

On the Wiki site re: Amplitude Modulation, see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_modulation

-it states, "It is assumed that  \$\omega_m \ << \omega_c\$,"

...which means that the frequency of the modulation is always lower than the frequency of the carrier.

Anyhow, my question, what if we did not assume that?

Is the reverse possible ?

---

more question added, 12/14/2013 Dan Jenson

Guys, thanks so far, I am coming along in my understanding because you all articulate precisely; and so with good respect to you all I would like to continue a little further.

Please let me go on and detail my question  more precisely.
I guess that my aim is a mathematical question per wave theory and I am using AM theory as a starting point.

Question: In wave theory, when one wave amplitude modulates another in a non-linear mixer the "signals" multiply and the frequencies add, and (as far as subtracting goes), the higher freq, subtracts the lower since we are dealing in semi-conductors and vacuum tubes which deal in like charges, namely electrons.

But now what if, let’s say the vacuum tube rf amp was a little gassy and glowed blue with some plasma when transmitting thus ionizing the actual gas atoms and (once again) “thus” bringing a proton gyro-magnet into the equation.  Since this mentioned particle is opposite in charge to the electron can we now bring into our applied math equation my forwarded “B-A”namely the ‘missing’ lower freq. wave modulator minus-ing the higher freq. carrier thus giving a negative resultant ?

My question again, re: wave theory, given the needed parameters, does the “B-A” math exist in reality or even virtual?

---

added 12/15/2013

My question launches from an electronics understanding of heterodyning to wave theory itself. I was simply wondering why the author of the referenced wiki site stated the equation as an "assumption" ?

I 'believe' that if hypothetically an opposite charge were included into the equation then maybe my proposed math could find validity.

Please, in wave analysis can we describe the why and where-to-fore of the
\$\omega_m \ << \omega_c\$,  equation mentioned above in essence as a simplistic intuitive of why this is true in wave theory ?

AM is the perfect example and so the question remains valid.

Granted the question goes on to model a yet untested hypothesis related to plasma physics,
but (!) I do not wish to conjecture this far I merely am looking for some sounding board commentary on how we can assume to conclude our understanding at this mentioned assumption?

Gentlemen, please, 
sincerely, Dan Jenson

Comment: Signal 'A' heterodynes with 'B', they output 'A', 'A+B', 'B', 'A-B'. Whether 'A' or 'B' is higher / lower / or the same frequency.

Comment: I was wondering namely with regards to AM heterodyning where is the 'B-A' ?

Comment: I mean if freq.C (carrier) is 20mhz and freq.M (modulator) is 10khz then I can see all of the resultant heterodynes mentioned above but I 'intuit' that there seems to be a 'fM-fC' missing which would equate negative.

Comment: I mean if freq.C (carrier) is 20mhz and freq.M (modulator) is 10khz then I can see all of the resultant heterodynes mentioned above but I 'intuit' that there seems to be a 'fM-fC' missing which would equate negative. Namely, 10,000.hz -20,000,000.hz equals (-19,990,000hz) .

Comment: AM  RF carrier heterodyned with Audio, outputs the original (RF) & (Audio) & (RF+Audio[upper sideband]) & (RF-Audio[lower sideband]). The transmitter blocks the Audio from its output. At the receiver the "Local Oscillator" is heterodynes all frequencies arriving from the mixer, only the "Intermediate Frequency" is amplified & sent to the Detector. The Bandwidth of the "IF" circuit allows the Carrier, USB & LSB through. The "IF" or the "LO" can be above or bellow the Carrier frequency with the "IF" being the sum or difference of the Carrier & "LO". FM transmitting is different than AM.

Comment: FM RF carrier frequency is varied by the Audio frequency. It is called "Deviation" & can produce either "Positive" or "Negative" frequency shift. As with AM, at the receiver the "Local Oscillator" is heterodynes all frequencies arriving from the mixer, only the "Intermediate Frequency" is amplified & sent to the Detector. The "Detector" circuit is different than that found in an AM receiver. The incoming FM frequency heterodyned with a "LO" will produce a "Sum" & "Difference" frequency, only one will be selected in the designed as the "IF" frequency.

Comment: The FM "IF" amplifier will have a wider "Bandwidth" than AM, to allow for the FM frequency "Deviation". A little known AM principle is to combine a "Positive" deviation "Narrow Band FM" with a "Negative" deviation "Narrow Band FM" signals at the antenna. It will produce an AM signal with 100% modulation, with no over modulation, and an even power demand for the power station.

Comment: The question has now changed far beyond the scope of the original question thus invalidating the answers. This makes a nonsence of the answers so I'm voting to close this question because of that. @Dan - you've got to pay some respect the the Q and A format for this site and if you change things like you have you can expect this sort of reaction. I'd advise you to restore the original question, up/down-vote/accept answers that are applicable and begin a new question.

Answer (score 1):

> Anyhow, my question, what if we did not assume that?

Demodulation is still possible, but much harder, so much harder that there is easier to transmit the signal without any modulation.  And that is for a single signal.  And obviously one is using modulation so that we can carry the signal using other frequencies than those of the signal itself (so that one multiplex several signals, or because those frequencies are too noisy to be usefull), and that would not be true in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Amplitude modulation in it's simplest mathematical form is one signal multiplied by the other ie A times B. It makes no difference if I call it B times A. It's still a modulation and reversing the carrier and modulation frequency makes no difference.

Is it a new form of modulation? No it isn't.

Does it ever get used this way? It sure does - when down-converting a radio signal to an intermediate frequency (I.F.) the modulated wanted signal is mixed\$^1\$ with a carrier of lower\$^2\$ frequency. The outcome of this is that your wanted higher frequency signal is made much lower in frequency. The carrier in this situation is called the local oscillator and this technique is used in almost every broadcast receiver you can buy from your electrical store.

---

\$^1\$ Mixing is the name RF engineers give to imply multiplication/modulation.

\$^2\$ Down-converting to an I.F. can be equally done with a frequency that is higher than the wanted modulated signal but normally it's a lower frequency.

Comment: That's actually double sideband, not what is commonly meant by amplitude modulation.

Comment: @OlinLathrop any form of amplitude modulation relies on A multiplied by B. If A (or B) happens to have a dc level (making it a two quadrant multiplication and not 4) then that is irrelevant. It isn't a new form of modulation.

Comment: I agree what the OP is talking about is not a new form of modulation. I'm just saying that "AM" is commonly used to describe the two-quadrant version as you put it. The full four-quadrant is more commonly called double sideband.  In the general case, these are all forms of "product modulation". I think we're actually agreeing here, just maybe a slight difference in terms.

Comment: @OlinLathrop yeak no problem Olin but 4-quadrant is normally called "suppressed carrier" or double sideband suppressed carrier (DSBSC) - double sideband could mean regular broadcast AM because it doesn't specifically imply suppressed carrier (as per 4Q).